# Case insensitive seach Solr 5.5

Tags: solr

I am trying to create a very simple solr application where i will index title and id. I want to search title without any case and I have used LowerCaseFilterFactory filter but some how it is not working. I want stemming search support too.

Below is my schema file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema name="example" version="1.5">

   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
 <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
 <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
</fieldType>
</schema>
```

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using "`KeywordTokenizerFactory`" for indexing and "`WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`" for querying.

Here the output for both of it is different.

`KeywordTokenizerFactory` keeps the word as it is . It wont tokenize the word/text.

But `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` is a tokenizer that divides text at whitespaces.

`PorterStemFilterFactory` : a normalization process that removes common endings from words.

```
Example: "riding", "rides", "horses" ==> "ride", "ride", "hors".
```

You can try modifying the field Type.

Now it is left to your requirement that how do you want to implement the search and then decide the to build the custom `fieldType` or may use the `fieldType` mentioned in the `schema.xml`

You can try a field Type like below for your field title

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

OR

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/> 
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>  
       </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: I tried same but still case insensitive search is not working. I am using managed-schema instead of schema.xml

Comment: did you verified the same on solr admin UI? After the changes did you restart the server & re-index the data?